# Move actionscript from external .as to timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, flash-cs5.5

I want to ask how can I make an external script .as can be moved to the timeline??
i dont understand about as3..
plis help me :(

this is the script that i want to move to timeline

```
    package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*; 
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    //import fl.display.ProLoader;

    dynamic public class bismillah extends MovieClip
    {
        public var ba:MovieClip;
        public var scorebox:TextField;
        public var alif:MovieClip;
        public var dal:MovieClip;
        public var tong:MovieClip;
        public var book:MovieClip;
        public var objArray:Array;
        public var targetArray:Array;
        public var objek:MovieClip;
        public var original_x:Number;
        public var original_y:Number;
        public var score:int;
        public var i:int;
        public var tombol1:MovieClip;
        var singleLoader:Loader = new Loader();

        public function bismillah()
        {
            stop();
            addFrameScript(0, frame1);
            tombol1 = Object(root).tombol1 as MovieClip;
            tombol1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, tes);
            return;

        }// end function

        public function tes(param : MouseEvent) : void
        {
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("dragdragon.swf");
            //singleLoader.unload();
            singleLoader.load(req);
            addChild(singleLoader);

        }

        public function down(param1:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            objek = MovieClip(param1.target);
            original_x = objek.x;
            original_y = objek.y;
            addChild(objek);
            objek.startDrag();
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp);
            return;
        }// end function

        public function stageUp(param1:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp);
            objek.stopDrag();
            if (objek.dropTarget)
            {
                if (objek.dropTarget.parent.name == "book")
                {
                if ((objek == alif) || (objek == ba)){  //yg perlu diganti
                    objek.x = objek.dropTarget.parent.x;
                    objek.y = objek.dropTarget.parent.y + 50;
                    objek.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
                    objek.buttonMode = false;
                    var _loc_2:Number;
                    objek.scaleY = 0.4;
                    objek.scaleX = _loc_2;
                    objek.alpha = 0.6;
                    score+=5;
                    scorebox.text = "Score: " + score;
                }
                else {
                objek.x = objek.dropTarget.parent.x;
                    objek.y = objek.dropTarget.parent.y + 50;
                    objek.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
                    objek.buttonMode = false;
                    var _loc_2:Number;
                    objek.scaleY = 0.4;
                    objek.scaleX = _loc_2;
                    objek.alpha = 0.6;
                    score-=2;
                    scorebox.text = "Score: " + score;}
                }

                else if (objek.dropTarget.parent.name == "tong")
                {
                    if (objek == dal) { //yg perlu diganti
                    objek.x = objek.dropTarget.parent.x;
                    objek.y = objek.dropTarget.parent.y + 50;
                    objek.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
                    objek.buttonMode = false;
                    var _loc_2:Number;
                    objek.scaleY = 0.4;
                    objek.scaleX = _loc_2;
                    objek.alpha = 0.6;
                    score+=5;
                    scorebox.text = "Score: " + score;
                }
                else {
                    objek.x = objek.dropTarget.parent.x;
                    objek.y = objek.dropTarget.parent.y + 50;
                    objek.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
                    objek.buttonMode = false;
                    var _loc_2:Number;
                    objek.scaleY = 0.4;
                    objek.scaleX = _loc_2;
                    objek.alpha = 0.6;
                    score-=2;
                    scorebox.text = "Score: " + score;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                objek.x = original_x;
                objek.y = original_y;
            }
            return;
        }// end function

        public function returnToOriginalPosition() : void
        {
            return;
        }// end function

        function frame1()
        {
            objArray = [alif, dal, ba]; //yg perlu diganti
            targetArray = [book, tong];
            score = 0;
            scorebox.text = "Score: " + score;
            i = 0;
            while (i < objArray.length)
            {

                objArray[i].buttonMode = true;
                objArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
                i++;
            }
            return;
        }// end function


    }

}
```

Please is it possible someone to help me to move the code to timeline??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create new MovieClip in the fla library
2. Select "Export for ActionScript" check box
3. Enter the name of your as file in the input field "Class"
4. put the *.as files in the same folder as fla file.

Don't forget to create all nested clips in your new MovieClip - *ba*, *scorebox*, etc.

Comment: oh i see..but if i want to change the script, i had to change in .as or in movieclip??if in movieclip how i do it?

Comment: in *as. Generally, all scripts should be in *.as files it make the search simpler and there you can use more powerful IDE for editing as files (Flash Builder, Flash Develop or IDEA).

Comment: my friend also said so..but I am confused which one is better :)
thanx for your answer :)